# Jettison can not convert json string to json object when there is an element has empty string value

Tags: json, rest, apache-camel, typeconverter, jettison

My application is using camel rest (2.15.2) to catch a POST json String and then uses jettison to convert to a JSON Object. It is working fine with normal request.

```
POST request: {"request"={"lname"="aaa", "fname"="bb"}}

1. String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
2. JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(body);
```

When i debug, variable `body = {request={lname=aaa, fname=bb}}`.
And line 2 returns a JSONObject. so far so good

if we try to another the request:

```
{"request"={"lname"="   ", "fname"="aa"}}
```

then `body = {request={lname=   , fname=aa}}`
line2 returns Exception.

Could you please help me to fix this issue:  convert json string which contains element has empty value string to json object.

The above request is acceptable in my scenarios.

Error:

> org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: Missing value. at character
>   15 of  {request={lname=   , fname=aa}}    at
>   org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:463)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:356)
>     at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:230)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONTokener.newJSONObject(JSONTokener.java:412)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:327)
>     at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:230)
>     at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:311)

Comment: Well, something seems to be stripping your quotations and it seems to happen before the message gets on the exchange. So actually no problem with Jettison i would say?

Comment: Yes, I agree. Is there any way that jettison can work with that kind of request?

Comment: No, you should investigate why your quotations are stripped from the string

Comment: Camel-rest stripped off the double quote. Currently, to bypass this issue, i have to manually replace all "blank " by "double quote". But i still prefer a way that jettison can work with it Or camel-rest stops stripping off the double quote. Pattern.compile("=\\s*,").matcher(body).replaceAll("=\"\",");

Comment: Sounds very weird anyway. Jettison won't be able to handle it at least. And I don't know why they are getting stripped, probably because of how you are sending the data or some config of the restConfig? Try to debug it

Comment: gson and org.json do it by default.